# Java - Spring boot query that return an object made from two different tables

Tags: java, spring

I have two entities that have references by id.

One entity is a candidate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "eupass_candidate", schema = "hrast")
public class Candidate{

    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String munic;
    private String postalCode;
    // getters and setters

}
```

And the other one is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "eupass_pdffile", schema = "hrast")
public class PDFFile implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -753514667628201960L;
private long id;
private byte[] pdfFile;
private Long idCandidate;
```

Now I need to do a join of this two tables and retrieve the candidate first name, last name and the pdf if it has any.

I managed this with the following query:

```
SELECT fname, lname, pdf_file 
FROM hrast.eupass_candidate  
LEFT OUTER join hrast.eupass_pdffile 
     ON (hrast.eupass_candidate.id = hrast.eupass_pdffile.id_candidate)
```

Finally I would like to save the result in an object and send it to the front end application.

I understand that I can write the query annotation in an extended CrudeReopository, but in witch one.

- Do I need another object
- Or does java let you create an in place object just for this purpose

Comment: You can use a POJO with the fields you need to combine results from different tables

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and I'll post the feed back.

Comment: What's the association between a candidate and a PDF file?  Can a candidate have many files, or is a single file bound to a single candidate?

Comment: The candidate atm have only one PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this approach?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "eupass_pdffile", schema = "hrast")
public class PDFFile implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -753514667628201960L;
    private long id;
    private byte[] pdfFile;
    private Long idCandidate;
    //@ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="id_candidate") //or whatever your column name is.
    private Candidate candidate ;
}
```

Comment: This would be useful, but I at the moment it's not possible to do so (some implementation problems). But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Do I need another object?*

Yes as written by @ngueno  in comment you need POJO object which hold result of your join (firstName, lastName, pdfFile)

If your requirement is not to use JPA relationship and on your own if you have to manage it then, you can write query in any of the repository class either in CandidateRepository or PDFFileRespositry.

For Example:

```
import com.example.customquerywithjpa.dto.CandidatePDFFile;
import com.example.customquerywithjpa.entity.Candidate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface CandidateRepository extends JpaRepository<Candidate, Long> {

    // Inner Join
    @Query("SELECT new com.example.customquerywithjpa.dto.CandidatePDFFile(c.firstName, c.lastName, p.pdfFile) from Candidate c INNER JOIN PDFFile p ON (c.id=p.idCandidate) WHERE c.id =:candidateId")
    List<CandidatePDFFile> fetchCandidateAndPDFFIleByCandidateId(@Param("candidateId") long candidateId);

    // Left outer join
    @Query("SELECT new com.example.customquerywithjpa.dto.CandidatePDFFile(c.firstName, c.lastName, p.pdfFile) from Candidate c LEFT OUTER JOIN PDFFile p ON (c.id=p.idCandidate) WHERE c.id =:candidateId")
    List<CandidatePDFFile> fetchCandidateFirstNameLastNameAndItsPDFFileIfExists(@Param("candidateId") long candidateId);
}
```

For more understanding I have created sample project and test considering your use case with the assumption that one candidate can have zero or more pdf files. Please refer below github repository:

[spring-data-jpa-query-that-return-an-custom-objectmade-from-two-different-tables](https://github.com/shambhand/blog-examples/tree/master/custom-query-with-jpa)

Comment: I tried your solution and I get the errors from the SQL statement. The error is on the first "." (Obviously I have used my path to the defined POJO). So I have removed the new end the path and than I get the error: No converter found capable of converting from type

Comment: Hi, Could you please paste the code snippet and exception here or if possible link to your source.

The example I pushed to  [github repository](https://github.com/hodorgeek/spring-boot-examples/tree/master/custom-query-with-jpa) is in working state, may be some query syntax specific things have been missed with your code.

Comment: Ok so my Candidate wit PDF
`import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;;

@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CandidateWithPdf {

 private String fname;
 private String lname;
 private byte[] pdf_file;`

Comment: @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "/candidates", itemResourceRel = "candidates", collectionResourceRel = "candidates")
public interface CandidateRepository extends JpaRepository<Candidate, Long> {
  
  @Query(nativeQuery = true,
   value = 
  "SELECT " +
  " 'com.dinit.hrast.entity.CandidateWithPdf(fname, lname, pdf_file)' " + 
    "FROM hrast.eupass_candidate " + 
    "LEFT OUTER join hrast.eupass_pdffile " + 
    "on (hrast.eupass_candidate.id = hrast.eupass_pdffile.id_candidate)")
  List<CandidateWithPdf> listAllCandidates();
}

Comment: And the last is the Controller
@GetMapping("/listCandidates")
 public ResponseEntity<List<CandidateWithPdf>> listCandidatesWithPdf() {
  List<CandidateWithPdf> candidatesWithPdf;
  candidatesWithPdf = candidateRepository.listAllCandidates();
  
  HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  responseHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  return new ResponseEntity<>(candidatesWithPdf, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
 }

Comment: @gregorvojvoda In your repository class you have used native SQL query and tried to mix its syntax with JPA Query, I think if its native query then it will return Object[];
I would recommend to use the pure JPA query for this.

For example:

`@Query("SELECT new com.example.customquerywithjpa.dto.CandidatePDFFile(c.firstName, c.lastName, p.pdfFile) from Candidate c LEFT OUTER JOIN PDFFile p ON (c.id=p.idCandidate) WHERE c.id =:candidateId")
List<CandidatePDFFile> fetchCandidateFirstNameLastNameAndItsPDFFileIfExists(@Param("candidateId") long candidateId);`