# Spring Boot native join query does not fetch table 2 data

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**My Interface code is:**

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT rates.*, currency.* " +
                "FROM rates JOIN currency on rates.currency_id = currency.id " +
                "WHERE rates.date_id = :date_id",
        nativeQuery = true
)
public List<Rates> findRatesByDateId(@Param("date_id")int date_id) throws CustomException;
```

**My repository:**

```
List<Rates> result = ratesRepositoryBase.findRatesByDateId(date_id);
```

It only returns data of rates(Table) and not showing any data of currency table. How to get data of currency table also, can anyone please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - Spring boot query that return an object made from two different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53885505/java-spring-boot-query-that-return-an-object-made-from-two-different-tables)

Comment: `SELECT rates.*, currency.* ` can just be written like `SELECT *  ` but it's better if you list only columns that you required to return. Perhaps something like `SELECT rates.date_id, rates.col2, currency.col1, currency.col2 ...` etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Let's see the problem first** 
you are getting only rates data only because of

```
public List<Rates> findRatesByDateId(@Param("date_id")int date_id);
```

Check the return type  this entity class has the only field related to rates.... that's why you are not getting **currency table** data

**How to get data of currency table also ?** 
**Method 1-** use @OneToMany relational mapping with @JoinColumn.

**Method 2-** If you want to use native query only then create a new model/entity having all the fields of rates, currency  (let say we name it RateCurrency)  then-

```
public List<RateCurrency> findRatesByDateId(@Param("date_id")int date_id)
```